# How to make bar of an audio player

Tags: jquery

My problem is that `result_sect` is not correct and each time audio ends, the white bar doesn't end on time, it ends sooner or very late.

How can I fix this?

```html
<div class="time-container">
  <div class="time-passed"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.play').on('click', function() {
  $audio = $('audio');
  $audio.trigger('play');

  duration = $audio.duration;

  // This may be wrong formula
  result_sect = sect = duration / 100;

  playing_interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (result_sect >= 100) {
      clearInterval(playing_interval);
    }
    $('.time-passed').css('width', result_sect + '%');
    result_sect = result_sect + sect;
  }, result_sect);
});
```

```css
.time-container {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 8px;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

.time-passed {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An audioelement has a timeupdate event, which you should use to update your progress bar width. You shouldn't use settimeouts for this.

Also you could consider using the `<progress>` tag instead of a div.

```js
$('#play').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
});

$('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
    $('.time-passed').css("width", this.currentTime / this.duration * 100 + '%');
});
```

```css
.time-container
        {
            background-color: #f00;
            height: 8px;
            width: 80%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .time-passed
        {
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1px;
            left: 0px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-container">
    <div class="time-passed"></div>
</div>

<audio src="http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/gtr-nylon22.mp3" id="player"></audio>  
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the ratio that modifies the current progress and is displayed in width on your progress bar:

```
  currentProgressBarLenght = currentTime * 100 / duration
```

For example if you have a 360 seconds audio that has been paying for 36 seconds you get a 10 width on the progress bar. currentProgresBarlength = 36s * 100/ 360 that makes us 10 px or whatever.

Comment: result_sect = playing_interval * 100 / duration